# how to add, muiltiply and divide numbers in a bracket

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if anyone could assist me in solving this math using vb net

Dmj = 1(4+0.5)+2(1.5+0.5) + 2(2+0.5)+7(3+0.5) /12 12 is the total of numbers outside the bracket (i.e. 1+2+2+7)
 = 4.5+4+5+24.5
    12
= 38/12
=3.17

Below is the code which does not give me the correct answer 3.17

Public Class Form3

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Maxnumber As Integer
    Dim total, total2 As Integer
    Dim input, input2 As Integer
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim accu As Integer
    Maxnumber = CInt(InputBox("How many numbers to you wish to sum?"))
    total = 0

    For x = 1 To Maxnumber
        input = CInt(InputBox("Enter the number"))

        input2 = CInt(InputBox("Enter the Distance"))

        If input And input2 = Nothing Then
            Exit For
        Else
            num = CDbl(input)
            accu = CDbl(input2)

            total += num
            total2 = num * (accu + 0.5)

        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(total2)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: If you want to successfully parse an arithmetic expression like this, in general you will need to write some sort of parser.

Comment: Change your variable types to double, you are losing precision and turn option strict on now... there is more, but thats not the problem.

Comment: When you use And in an If statement the expressions on each side of the And must evaluate to True or False. `If x = Nothing And y = Nothing Then` Your If statement has another problem. input and input2 are Integers (a Value type) so they cannot be Nothing. They immediately become zero when you declare them.

Comment: Your code example does not reflect the question you are asking.

Comment: Go into your projects property pages and set Option Strict to On.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Or at the top of the file: `Option Strict On` :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this code

**I have tested this code in visual studio 2010 successfully**

```
 Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Maxnumber As Double
    Dim total, total2, total3, total4 As Double
    Dim input, input2 As Double
    Dim num As Double
    Dim accu As Double
    Maxnumber = CDbl(InputBox("How many numbers to you wish to sum?"))
    total = 0

    For x = 1 To Maxnumber
        input = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the number"))

        input2 = CDbl(InputBox("Enter the Distance"))

        If input = 0 And input2 = 0 Then
            Exit For
        Else
            num = CDbl(input)
            accu = CDbl(input2)
            total += num

            total2 = num * (accu + 0.5)
            total3 = total3 + total2
            total4 = total3 / total
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(total4)
End Sub
```

Comment: This line is wrong and doesn't do what you think it does:  `If input And input2 = Nothing Then`

Comment: I am not changing this line because warning to the author already given by @mery. I only improve his code to get correct answer. Sorry for any language mistake, i am not well in english.